# ASP.NET MVC two diffrent approaches to get form values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating my own ModelBinder.

I get form values from `HttpContext` obtained from property `ControllerContext.HttpContext`.

But there is another way to get this context - as `ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext`.

Are there any major differences in these approaches? Would any of them fail under some circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source code for `RequestContext`:

```
public RequestContext RequestContext
{
  get
  {
    if (this._requestContext == null)
      this._requestContext = new RequestContext(this.HttpContext ?? (HttpContextBase) new ControllerContext.EmptyHttpContext(), this.RouteData ?? new RouteData());
    return this._requestContext;
  }
  set
  {
    this._requestContext = value;
  }
}
```

So unless you do something specific to set the `RequestContext` on your controller (as may happen in unit testing, for example), the `RequestContext.HttpContext` will be the same as the `HttpContext` property itself.

You are unlikely to run into situations where these two values would be different.

Comment: Yeah, but RequestContext.HttpContext will never be a null whereas there is a possibility for HttpContext to be null.

Comment: @greenshade: no, the `HttpContext` property getter has a similar null check, so it'll always return a non-null value. https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/4.0.20710.0/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v4.0/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerContext.cs